# how to call two url in one webview in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to call two url in one webview one after the another but how i know i can load one url in webview but to call two url please help me one this how to timeinterval on both the url
    this is mu single url if but i have to give here two url the how to give and call them

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CheapFlightsAppDelegate* app=(CheapFlightsAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true;

    NSLog(@"Book: %@",app.selectedOutgoingFlight.FlightKey);
    NSLog(@"Book: %@",app.selectedInComingFlight.FlightKey);

    NSString *hel = @"http://www.bookryanair.com/SkySales/FRSelect.aspx?AvailabilityInputFRSelectView %24ButtonSubmit=Select%20and%20Continue&AvailabilityInputFRSelectView%24m arket1="; 
    NSString *hel1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&",app.selectedOutgoingFlight.FlightKey];
    NSString *hel2 = @"AvailabilityInputFRSelectView%24market2="; 
    NSString *hel3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&",app.selectedInComingFlight.FlightKey]; 
    NSString *hel4 = @"__EVENTARGUMENT=&__EVENTTARGET=";



    NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@",hel,hel1,hel2,hel3,hel4];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    spinner.hidden = NO;
    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSLog(@"Book: %@",urlAddress);

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    webView.delegate = self;

}
```

Comment: hey rockey use new answer it work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set new `url` of `NSURLRequest` and call `[webView loadRequest:requestObj];` after any time interval you want again.

[NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) will help you to call method after some interval.

```
// after loading first url:
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(loadNewUrl:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

//somewhere in delegate define selector
- (IBAction)loadNewUrl:(NSTimer *)timer
{
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/stevejobs"];

     //URL Requst Object
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

     //Load the request in the UIWebView.
     [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

**UPDATED:**
Implement in your `` methods to detect when webview finished loading first url:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Comment: how to give time interval in both please tell me

Comment: how do i know first url is complete before second url is call

Comment: friend only first url is loading  secondurl is not loading

Answer (score 2):

```
 use this method
   NSURLRequest *request=[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670889/how-to-call-two-url-in-one-webview-in-iphone/7670992#7670992"]];
     [webView loadRequest:request];
     [self performSelector:@selector(loadAnother:) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];

-(IBAction)loadAnother:(id)sender{
     NSURLRequest *requests=[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683196/uitableview-with-text-that-is-both-right-aligned-and-indented"]];
    [webView loadRequest:requests];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In "webViewDidFinishLoad" delegate method get the current URL thats loaded using

currentURL = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;

Then check if it matches with your first URL and if it does, Load the second URL that you need to call. If you want, call this second URL after some time using a timer.