# UITableView with text that is both right-aligned and indented

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, alignment, indentation

I wanted to make a `UITableView` with text that is both right-aligned and indented as depicted in the image below:

[image]

Unfortunately, I can not do this by writing :-

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight; 
cell.indentationLevel = 10; // or even -10
```

Can this be done using `UITableView`'s properties? If not, the only way I could think of is using `[myString drawInRect:withFont:];` but I would like to go through methods based on alignment and indentation before getting into that *[I have already written code for that :-) ]*, so other work-arounds are welcome!

**Additional info**: The indentation varies with accelerometer values so I can not have hard-coded Label frame positions. I've uploaded sample code at [github](https://github.com/aakash272/Dynamic-information-display-on-touch-screen-phones/tree/master/floatingList/floatingList) in which I've used only the alignment and indentation info so far, so continuing to use that would make this easier.

Comment: u can create your own uilabel and add it to the cell's contentview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass `UITableViewCell` and you can position the `frame` of the text label however you like. In the `if` statement where you `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` where a reusable cell doesn't exist, just modify the `frame` and then set the label to use the adjusted frame with `setFrame`. The autoresizing mask should remain the same.

Comment: So, is there no way to set both right-alignment and indentation? I'll have to rewrite the code then :(

Comment: I might be doing it wrong...I used setFrame: and the labels did'nt move. could you take a look at my code at github(rootViewcontroller at the link given above)

Comment: I used the exact way you've described and it works now...I've uploaded the updated code at [github](https://github.com/aakash272/Dynamic-information-display-on-touch-screen-phones) :)

Comment: :) Cool. Glad I could help out. Sorry for not looking at the code earlier, I've been busy at work.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create your own custom cells and place a UITextLabel in the cell, and make the UITextLabel's alignment right aligned.

Also set the autoresizing mask of the UITextLabel to the right so the indentation distance stays the same no matter the orientation.